# Adding Django intellisense to Pycharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I created a django project outside of PyCharm and now I am trying to find out how to add code-completion capabilities to the editor.  Where in settings can I add django intellisense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I fixed this by adding the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to the default run configurations.

Try adding this variable, and setting the value to `<projectname>.settings`, and run one of your project files:

[image]
[image]

PS: You can also add this environment variable to the console environment under:

File -> Settings -> Console -> Python Console -> Environment Variables

This will make it possible to use the integrated PyCharm console to access your project, which is way better than using the console that ships with Django.